# solr multiple ranges on single field cause error

Tags: solr, edismax

I have a drupal site that uses solr. It works fine, except when I have 2 range queries for the same field, then it breaks and I get the following error:

> An error occurred while trying to search with Solr: "400" Status: Bad Request: Bad Request{"error":{"msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '((im_field_products_collection$field_products$field_product_winch_line_length:[\"90\"': Encountered \"\" at line 1, column 83.\nWas expecting one of:\n \"TO\" ...\n  ...\n  ...\n ","code":400}} .

And this is the query that the module produces for that field

> (({!tag=facet:field_products_collection:field_products:field_product_winch_line_length}((im_field_products_collection$field_products$field_product_winch_line_length:["90" TO *]) (im_field_products_collection$field_products$field_product_winch_line_length:[* TO "99"]))) OR ({!tag=facet:field_products_collection:field_products:field_product_winch_line_length}((im_field_products_collection$field_products$field_product_winch_line_length:["100" TO *]) (im_field_products_collection$field_products$field_product_winch_line_length:[* TO "109"]))))

Everything looks right to me, and it works fine with just a single range query on a field, does anyone have any idea what part of the query would be causing the error? I am using the edismax parser.

Answer (score 0):

After hours looking into this, the module was adding the tag field to the beginning of each part of the query, which SOLR didn't like. By only have the tag comment at the beginning and removing the second one, the query appears to work just fine now.